# Histogram in JMP 11

Tags: histogram, jmp

While plotting histogram in JMP 11, the option to set the bin width is not available. I also tried doing it with the axis settings, but the X-axis setting is disabled (X-axis has the variable values on horizontal histogram).

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: This cannot be migrated to SO in its present form as it doesn't meet the standards to be on topic at the destination.

Answer (score 3):

On the X axis, Click and drag on an axis to rescale it. Alternatively, hover over the axis until you see a hand. Then, double-click on the axis and set the parameters in the Axis Specification window. Hope this helps !

Comment: Did you try this?